# How to allow a node to be dynamic and affected by gravity while being immovable?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am working on a game where obstacles drop from the top of the screen (like Tetris), and the player is at the bottom of the screen moving around. I am trying to make it so my obstacles are dynamic and affected by gravity, but when the player comes in contact with them, I don't want the obstacle to move (which it does because it is using the SpriteKit physics engine). Is there a way to have the obstacles affected by gravity and dynamic while being immovable?

```
    objectSprite.physicsBody!.friction = 0.0
    objectSprite.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    objectSprite.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true

    objectSprite.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.0
    objectSprite.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Max, can you give more information about your physics settings? There is code but it's not enough to understand better how your object are involved in this project.

Comment: Did you consider setting `dynamic = false` after a contact is made?

Comment: I am lost here,  how can an object be affected by gravity, but not move

Comment: if you want the object to fall, but not have other objects push it,  then set the mass really high

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want the falling object to be moved by contact with the player? Try setting the player's collisionBitMask to be equal to the falling object's category, but for the fallen object's collisionBitMask NOT to include the player.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @SteveIves, this worked perfectly

Comment: Glad to be able to help. So does the player get pushed/moved by the falling object, which just continues on its own path? Shall make it an answer so you can upvote it? 